# Run node command line module from Java

Tags: java, node.js, npm, command-line, stdout

I'm trying to run [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) on a SVG string generated by my program. SVGO was installed globally with `npm install -g svgo` and can normally be run on the command line like this:

```
cat image.svg | svgo -i - -o - > image-opt.svg
```

I'm using standard input and output. The equivalent in Java would be:

```java
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("svgo", "-i -", "-o -").start();

BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

stdin.write("<svg>...</svg>");
stdin.flush();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stdout);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

I get a `java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed` error. If I don't flush, I get no output, `stdout.readLine()` returns null.

The `svgo.cmd` file is a script located in `%APPDATA%/npm`, generated by npm.

How can I use a node module from Java?

Comment: You may need to close stdin to signal that there's no more input.

Comment: I tried flushing and closing but I get an IOException. I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294711/how-to-use-processbuilder-to-continually-interact-with-a-cli-program/58297475#58297475) will help?